# Using fstream to read from a binary file and store the results in a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream, binaryfiles, stdvector

I'm working on a project for my CS202 class. I have a supplied binary file of unknown size called `data.dat` and need to read integers (which I don't know in advance) from the file and store them in a properly sized vector. I have to use `fstream()` for the filestream and I have to use the `reinterpret_cast<char *>()` for the conversion. My code looks like this:

```
fstream filestream2;
//reading binary data from supplied data.dat file
filestream2.open("data.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
vector<int> v;
filestream2.seekg(0, filestream2.end);
long length = filestream2.tellg();
v.resize(length);
filestream2.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&v[0]), length);
for(int num = 0; num < length; num++)
{
    cout << v[num] << " ";
}
```

In theory, the vector should hold all of the integers from the file and print them to stdout, but my output is simply about 50,000, 0s followed by `program exited with exit code 0`
I'm relatively new to C++ syntax and libraries and I just cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong for the life of me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use

```
filestream2.seekg(0, filestream2.end);
long length = filestream2.tellg();
```

you get the number of characters in the file, not the number of items in the vector. Consequently, you will need to use `length/sizeof(int)` when you want use the size of the vector.

```
v.resize(length);
```

is incorrect. It needs to be

```
v.resize(length/sizeof(int));
```

and

```
for(int num = 0; num < length; num++)
{
    cout << v[num] << " ";
}
```

is incorrect. It needs to be

```
for(int num = 0; num < length/sizeof(int); num++)
{
    cout << v[num] << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said that "you don't know in advance" which kind of data ( size of data) is stored in file. The main problem is to identify size of data and its datatype. So what can you do is, create custom formate file.

For ex.

- 1st byte of file will indicate type of data, (ex. I for integer, F for float, U for unsigned int, C for char, S for char* (string) so on)
- Next 4 bytes will be size of data ( required only for char* so it is optional)
- After that actual date will be started.

So data will be in file like

```
Cabcdefghijk
```

Here 1st byte is C so data will be char. So need to create vector of char type.

Next data size :

```
fstream.seekg(0, fstream.end);
long length = fstream.tellg(); //  length : 12

length -= 1; // 1st byte is indecator // length : 11

// length -= 4; // Optional : if you had write size of data
length = length / sizeof( char); //  sizeof( int) or sizeof( flot) or written in file.
// so in our case length will be 11;
```

Now you have data type and size of data, so create or resize vector accordingly.